# Keras input process with DataFrame variable length list of strings

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to build a TF/Keras model that takes in sequential feature and scalar features. The training data is from a Pandas DataFrame. The sequential feature for one example can be considered as a list of strings(or words of different length) under one column of the DataFrame. The words themselves can be seen as categorical, the number of unique words being limited. I am wondering what is the right order and method to process data of this kind? Possible steps include mapping the string to integers, padding/truncating to a fixed length

I was planning to convert the sequential features and scalar features into tensors following https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers. Then put the sequential features into a LSTM and the scalar feature into a MLP and use a FCN to combine their outputs. I am stuck at the data process step.

I have tried using keras.layers.StringLookup to convert the string list feature into integer list. But it complains that the nparray cannot be converted to tensor. And I am wondering should I first convert the list of strings into a string Tensor and then convert it into a integer Tensor? And what is the right order and method to process data of this kind.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as a first step you can convert your list of strings to tensors. To convert a string to tensor, you can use "tf.constant" function. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
s = ["dog", "cat"]
ts = tf.constant(s)
print(ts)
```

You get:

```
tf.Tensor([b'dog' b'cat'], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
```

Then you can use StringLookup and CategoryEncoding like in function get_category_encoding_layer() on
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers#categorical_columns

Comment: The sequential features are lists of strings. Lists have different length. `tf.constant` fails with `ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.`.    

Actually I tried converting it to ragged tensors first and then to tensor. It worked but it's very slow. Is there other workarounds? 

One case that might be related is that when reading from tfRecord files directly, we can tf.io.parse_single_example by providing a [`features`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_single_example#args) argument to indicating it's fixedLenFeature or varLenFeature.